# Como saber se três pontos estão no sentido horário ou não em C/C++?

Tags: c, c++, geometria

Dados três pontos p1, p2 e p3, qual é a melhor maneira de saber se essa ordem está no sentido horário, no sentido anti-horário, ou em nenhum dos dois (os três são colineares)?

Por exemplo, na imagem a seguir os pontos estão no sentido horário:

[image: Pontos no sentido horário.]

Neste mesmo caso, se a ordem fosse p1, p3, p2 eles estariam no sentido anti-horário.

Comment: E o que você já fez? Coloque um [mcve] e sua dúvida específica.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se você obtiver o produto cruzado dos segmentos em ambos os lados dos ângulos, e pegar o seu sinal, você terá a informação de qual sentido os pontos estão orientados, como mostra o código abaixo.

```
// == 0: colineares; > 0: horario; < 0: anti-horario
int ordem(double ax, double ay, double bx, double by, double cx, double cy) {
    double bax = ax - bx;
    double bay = ay - by;
    double bcx = cx - bx;
    double bcy = cy - by;

    return (bax * bcy - bay * bcx);
}

int main()
{
    printf("P1, P2, P3 como em SOpt_125794: %d\n", ordem(5, 0, 0, 2, 5, 4));
    printf("P3, P2, P1 como em SOpt_125794: %d\n", ordem(5, 4, 0, 2, 5, 0));
    printf("Colineares em sequencia: %d\n", ordem(0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2));
    printf("Colineares com terceiro ponto no meio: %d\n", ordem(0, 0, 4, 4, 2, 2));
    return 0;
}
```

Note que comparar exatamente com zero pode te dar alguns resultados falsos por causa da aproximação do ponto flutuante, então se você precisa de uma precisão maior, você pode usar algo do tipo (colineares se abs(ordem) < epsilon), onde epsilon é um valor bem pequeno.